# Find the number of orders related to each order size in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Need some help with a MySQL query to be used in a larger database. Simplified here, I need to find the number of orders related to each order size.

I've been trying to get the query to work with a lot of combinations like: COUNT(DISTINCT item) or GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT order_id), GROUP BYs, ORDER BYs, HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item_id), etc. but it's not turning out like I really need it to. Any help toward getting me going in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

In this example table named items, the person with an order_id of 1 ordered three items, the person with an order_id of 4 ordered only one item, the person with an order_id of 5 ordered two items, etc. At the moment, they can only order up to three items max, but in the future, more items could be added so the query needs to be written in a way that can scale to 4 items, 5 items, etc.

Table name is: items

```
item_id    order_id    item
-------------------------------
1          1           apple
2          1           orange
3          1           grape
4          2           grape
5          3           apple
6          3           orange
7          4           apple
8          5           orange
9          5           apple
10         6           apple
11         6           orange
12         6           grape
13         7           orange
14         8           grape
```

In this example, the query result would be:

```
Number_of_Orders        Total_Order_Size
----------------------------------------
4                       1
2                       2
2                       3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `group by` twice.

```
select item_count,count(*)
from (select order_id,count(*) as item_count
      from tbl 
      group by order_id
     ) t
group by item_count
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select num_items, count(*) as num_orders
from (select order_id, count(*) as num_items
      from t
      group by order_id
     ) o
group by num_items
order by num_items;
```